# TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, image, gif

I'm trying to make a looping GIF out of multiple images from a folder called 'images'. But I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sem/Desktop/gif/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    frame[0].save('result.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=230, loop=0)
TypeError: 'PngImageFile' object is not subscriptable
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Here is the code I used:

```py
import requests, random, urllib, os
from PIL import Image
import glob

frames = []
images = []
glob = glob.glob('*.png')

for x in os.listdir('images'):
    images.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/images/' + x)

for x in images:
    frame = Image.open(x)
    frames.append(frame)

frame[0].save('result.gif', format='GIF', append_images=frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=230, loop=0)
```

Comment: You have a typo in the last line - it should be `frames[0].save...`, not `frame[0].save...`. You're missing the `s` in `frames`.